# Make the two 3Dview Windows independent of each other

Tags: python, interface, source-code

I create two 3D viewport area, I wanted to separate the two areas and make their events independent of each other. One as left, the other as right. How can I achieve this? Maybe I should modify the C source code？[image]

Comment: Hello!  What exactly do you mean by 3D viewport "events" ?

Comment: @Gorgious Hi ! I think that is the operation only works on one 3Dview , not the other one.

Comment: If I understand correctly I don't think that's possible, operations are object-dependant, not viewport dependant